# GRASS add on v.delaunay3d won't start

Tags: grass-gis, add-ons

I'm following [this tutorial](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Triangle_Mesh#How_to_create_a_3D_TIN) and installed the GRASS add on v.delaunay3d.

[image]

When I try to open this module with duble-click or enter nothing happens. It doesn't open. Does anyone have experience with this? Perhabs, I need to install another add-on to make this one work?
What could be a reason that nothing happens?

I'm using Windows 10 and GRASS 7.8.2

I tried to install it once more via the gui and added the option "Systemwide installation (perhabs systemadministration rights are needed)". Now I get the following error message when installing the extention:

> Unable to create 'C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 7.8\docs\rest':

Perhabs that's the issue?

[image]

Comment: Please edit and add your operating system and GRASS GIS version you use.

Comment: Please try again to (re)install it as the Addon server has been recently fixed.

Comment: I have the same problem.
Windows10, GRASS 7.8.2 I downloaded the file (wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/grass78/x86_64/addons/grass-7.8.2/v.delaunay3d.zip), but that just contains a few empty folders, no files. I saved a blank "metadata" file (v.delaunay3d.html) in the Roaming\GRASS7\addons\docs\html folder, because one of the warning messages claimed the relevant metadata could not be found, but GRASS still claims "v.delaunay3d" is either falsely written or can't be found, despite the Module appearing properly under "Addons" on the "Modules" tab, and installing by various means.

Comment: WARNING: Extension <v.delaunay3d> already installed. Re-installing...
Downloading precompiled GRASS Addons <v.delaunay3d>...
Updating addons metadata file...
Updating private addons metadata file...
WARNING: No addons metadata available. Addons metadata file not updated.
Installation of <v.delaunay3d> successfully finished
(Fri Apr 17 10:19:42 2020) Command finished (5 sec)

Comment: The command "v.delaunay3d" is either written incorrectly
or
cannot be located.

Comment: [Contents of the file modules.xml; apart from the html file copied from online, none of these files exist] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE task SYSTEM "grass-addons.dtd"> <addons version="7"> <task name="v.delaunay3d"> <description>Creates a 3D triangulation from an input vector map containing points or centroids.</description> <keywords>vector,geometry,3D triangulation</keywords> <binary> <file>C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\GRASS7\addons\docs\man\man1\v.delaunay3d.1</file> <file>C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\GRASS7\addons\docs\html\v.delaunay3d.html</file> <file>C:\Users\...\Ap

Comment: I think I understood the issue and edited my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module [v.delaunay3d](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass7/manuals/addons/v.delaunay3d.html) is actually an addon. You need to install it with `g.extension`, either in the graphical user interface (see below) or from commmand line with `g.extension v.delaunay3d`.

[image: GRASS GIS addon manager]

Edit:

Since you are on Windows, you are affected by the compilation error on the server which provides the Windows GRASS GIS Addon binaries: 
http://wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/grass78/x86_64/addons/latest/logs/ --> v.delaunay3d
This addon requires the CGAL library which apparently isn't installed there and also missing from OSGeo4W (http://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/x86_64/versions.html).
Overall, I wonder why QGIS included it at all, perhaps for the Linux/Mac users.
You can of course [compile](https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/wiki/CompileOnWindows) it yourself on Windows but that's probably not trivial.

Comment: I did that already. When I tried to install it again I got the following message:

**WARNING: Extension <v.delaunay3d> already installed. Re-installing...
Downloading precompiled GRASS Addons <v.delaunay3d>...
Updating addons metadata file...
Updating private addons metadata file...
WARNING: No addons metadata available. Addons metadata file not updated.
Installation of <v.delaunay3d> successfully finished
(Sun Feb  2 19:58:33 2020) Command finished (2 sec)**

Do I need that "metadata file". Where do I get it?

Comment: I can't find it on:  https://github.com/OSGeo/grass-addons/tree/master/grass7/vector/v.delaunay3d

Comment: Please edit your question and add your operating system and GRASS GIS version you use as it matters for the installation of addons.

Comment: I edited my answer. In addition, we work on a better solution with the provision of binaries for Windows (maybe also Mac) but it remains complex...